# Is there a word meaning "Go" or "Go away!" in Italian languages or dialects that could explain the etymology of Romanian "Valea!"?

Tags: regional, etymology, latin

I am looking for clues on the obscure etymology of the (otherwise rather common) Romanian expression *Valea!*, a imperative mood formula meaning "Go away", "Be gone" or "Beat it".

Romanian has no authoritative and complete etymological dictionary at the moment. Those in existence are either partially outdated, incomplete, or dubious personal contributions. Anyway, I was not able to find an entry on this term in any etymological dictionary, but I have found a [source](https://dexonline.ro/definitie/valea/55459*) that mentions it as a slang (argot) term, which it most certainly is not. It is a popular, rural, regional expression (from southern Romania), that may have entered urban slang in regions where it was otherwise absent, but it is not a recent creation of the slang language.

In such obscure cases of Romanian etymology, looking for Italian clues is always a good idea. (For example, in this way I was able to find that the Romanian word *pitic* = "dwarf(ish)" is of Latin origin, unlike what some dictionaries claimed, as said [here](https://latin.stackexchange.com/a/18927/3284), because similar forms can be found in the Italian area - cf. Milanese: *pitinu*, Sardinian: *pithinnu*, *piticu*, *piticheddu*.)

At first view, *Valea!* looks like the Romanian noun *vale* ("valley", Italian *valle*) with the feminine postfixed definite article *a* (and I guess that's how it is seen by the dictionary that considers it a slang formation), but it is much closer both semantically and close enough morphologically to the Italian imperative mood *Vai!*, with the same meaning, of which I read [here](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/vai#%C3%89tymologie_5) that it might come from *vādō, vadere* (unlike *andare)*, from where descend Italian *guado* and Romanian *vad* (shallow, ford).

The origin of the common Romanian word for *to go* ([merge](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/merge#Etymology_2)) is different, but Romanian future tense of verbs is build with auxiliary forms [probably](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/va#Romanian) based on *vādō, vadere*, a root which is also reflected in another regional imperative expression (but much more rarely used), *va!* ("go!"), and in the formula *mai va*, literally "still goes", but  meaning "it will take some more time".

My intuition is that the etymology of *Valea!* should be considered in relation to that of the Italian *Vai!* and *Va!* (go away, go).

But what about that *L*? ***Is there some regional Italian language or dialect that has a parallel form including a *L*?***

---

I am asking this because I want to look at alternative possibilities—the other one being that *Valea!* is just the reduced imperative form of a verbal (composite) expression including the noun *vale* (valley): there are such expressions in Romanian, the best candidate being *a-și lua valea*, literally "take one's valley", meaning "to go away", much like in the French form [*aller à vau-l’eau*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/aller_%C3%A0_vau-l%E2%80%99eau) - "to go downhill, to go down the drain, to go awry", but where the verb "to go" is *a lua* (from Latin levāre, “to lift”, cf. Italian *levare*), normally meaning "to take", but also meaning "to go" when coupled with "road", "path" (*a lua calea*="to *take* the path", cf. Italian *prendere la strada*, French *prendre la route* etc). - Therefore, in this case *valley*=*vale* just means path/road (namely that defined by a water course, or a downhill path).

In relation to this alternative explanation, the question would be: *is there a case in Italian where a verbal form meaning "to go" or "go away" is coupled with or includes the noun* **valle** *(valley)?*

Comment: There is an Italian form 'va là', 'ma va là', that literally  means 'go away', but is used to say for example 'I dont believe you'.  From Treccani Dictionary: "Con sign. più vago in alcune esclamazioni: ehi là, ohi là, voci di richiamo o di rimprovero; va' là, mostrando di non credere a quanto altri dice: va' là!, ...". https://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/la/

Comment: @BakerStreet - The problem is that `là`, meaning "there" (which has  parallels in other Romance languages, like French: `qui est là?`) is a form completely absent in Romanian (without even a rare occurrence like in the case of `va`). Two such rarities (I'd say "Italianisms") in one word is too improbable a coincidence. - As I want to look at alternative explications I have posted this question, which might get even a positive answer, but the opposite direction (`Valea!` as vocative of a composite verbal form based on `vale`=valley) might be the right way to go in the end.

Comment: I'm not an expert, and I don't know Romanian, but why it seems to you so strange that some words Italian and Romanian have the same origin? They are both Romance languages, they may have  in common many words of Latin origin. 'Là' in Italian comes from the latin 'illac'.

Comment: As for you second question, in Italian there is the phrase 'andare a valle', with the same meaning as in French.

Comment: Couldn't it be just a deformation of “Va' via”?

Comment: @BakerStreet - `why it seems to you so strange that some words Italian and Romanian have the same origin?` - it's not that. Of course, I expect common words to have common roots, that's why I am looking for Italian parallels for Romanian etymologies. But, *the existence of a specific word in both languages has to be confirmed first*: in order to deduce that *Valea* is related to *va là*, we have to be sure something like `va` and `là` is present in Romanian. But the first is barely documented, while the second is certainly absent: the chance for it pop-up in "valea" is zero.

Comment: @BakerStreet - the Romanian equivalent for `là` (there) is `acolo`, or `colo` from Latin `eccum` +`illōc`, while `loc`  (<Lat. `locus`) means "place", equivalent of Italian `luogo`. So, the roots are the same, but while the resulting words are similar for "place", they are different for "there": there is no `là` in Romanian. Different forms (`là` and `acolo`) have same origin, but apparently similar forms (`va là` and `valea`) may and probably have different origins.

Comment: @BakerStreet - `in Italian there is the phrase 'andare a valle'` - could you give me more info on that? If the meaning is like that of French, then it's the same as in Romanian `a-și lua valea` (a rare but attested form). It would serve as a rather strong proof that `Valea!` might be just the vocative of that verbal expression `a-și lua valea`. (Why is that not clear in the first place to a Romanian? Because that verbal expression is not commonly used, I've dug it up from dictionaries when looking for etymologies.)

Comment: @DaG - `Couldn't it be just a deformation of “Va' via”?` - A Romanian word cannot be explained as a deformation of an Italian expression if that expression is *completely* absent in Romanian. And, what I said about `là` (see comments above), is also true about `via`: it is totally absent in Romanian. If you look it up, you'll find a neologism (like in "Via Appia", or from French: "go to London *via* Paris) or as a rare and unrelated homophone (`a via`=to live; `viață`=life, cf. it. `vita`). "Valea!" is an old form that cannot be explained by neologisms.

Comment: @ cipricus The phrase 'andare a valle' means 'to go downhill', but only in literal sense, it hasn't a figurative sense as 'to go awry'.

Comment: @BakerStreet - I said "vocative" a few times in my posts here by mistake: what I meant was "[imperative mood](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imperative_mood#English)".

Comment: @DaG - Romanian word for Italian `via` meaning "away" is `departe` (more [here](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/departe#Etymology)), but for `va via`="go away" the best equivalent is `du-te încolo`, literally "you go that way", where `încolo`=`în`+`colo`, `colo`=`acolo`="there"=It. `là`. So, you see Romanian has different words for `via` and `là`. If "Valea!" had been based on these it would have been something like `va+colo`, not `va+là`. So, most probably `valea!` is the shortened form of `ia-ți valea!`, which is the imperative mood of `a-și lua valea`=to go away (literally "take the valley")

Comment: @cipricus: “A Romanian word cannot be explained as a deformation of an Italian expression if that expression is completely absent in Romanian.” I see, thanks. I imagined that it might be some of a later loanword, or something similar, but I don't know the first thing about Romanian, so I stand corrected.

Comment: @DaG - No, it's I who stands corrected! The best of what I was hoping for would have been an Italian word closer morphologically to Romanian `valea`, based on a Latin root like `vale!`, which is a salute ("be healthy!", "good bye!") which in Spanish gave also the meaning of "permit to pass", and after incredibly transpiring in Romanian might have meant ironically "go away". But no, all we can find are good arguments *against* my initial "intuition". :)  - Latin `Vale!` in popular Romanian is too beautiful to be true!

Comment: This is not an answer, but Slavic languages have words similar to _valiti_ with the general meaning of "to throng, to move in large crowds", with imperatives generally resembling the Romanian word. Russian has the slang word _вали_ ("vali", with a final stress though), with exactly this meaning: "go away, get lost".

Comment: @Quassnoi - That sounds very promising, and not at all surprising! The impact of Slavic is huge in Romanian vocabulary. - Do you know examples from other Slavic languages (as the source of most Romanian Slavic words is — for geographical reasons — not Russian, but Bulgarian, and to a lesser degree Serbian, and their ancestors)?

Comment: @cipricus: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8F#Bulgarian, https://en.pons.com/translate/slovenian-english/valiti (sense II.2, of people). I believe most if not all Slavic languages have it.

Answer (score 3):

I hope this helps. As pointed out in the comment, the italian form "va là" is an expression used as "that's unbelievable" or "you're kidding me". The interesting thing is that in Brazilian Portuguese, there exists a regional slang that sounds like "va là" that has a similar meaning. The same goes for the Romanian *pitic*, which becomes the slang *pitico* in Brazilian Portuguese. Finally, there is the Brazillian Portuguese expression *Dale!*, which means the same thing as "Valea!", although sometimes it expresses motivation, like a "do it!". I don't have any sort of knowledge in Romanian, and neither about the origin of such expression, however, in both Italian and Portuguese it literally means "go away" and it would make sense if *Valea!* (also lit. meaning "go away") somehow came from *va là*, even if it looks improbable.

Comment: These examples, like those in the comments, are useful as proof *against* my first hypothesis or intuition that `valea!` might be related to `via!` etc. The *basic parts* for the Italian and Brazilian forms are different from what we can find in Romanian. See my comments under question with more details. If the same Latin root (`illoc/illac`) has *different* descendants in Italian and Romanian (ro. `acolo`, ital. `là`) or no descendants at all in Romanian (`via`), the Italian forms cannot be used to explain Romanian `valea!

Comment: More probably `valea!` is the shortened form of `ia-ți valea!`, which is the imperative mood of `a-și lua valea`=to go away (literally "take one's valley", where "valley" replaces "road"), like in English "Take the road!" or "Hit the road!"